# How does this output for the for loop works?

Tags: c#, for-loop

Hey guys I have exam testing me the output of the for loop. But I don't seem to get it how does this output becomes 11?

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int i;
        for (i = 1; i <= 10; i += 2)
        {
        }
        MessageBox.Show("The number is " + i);
    }
}
```

Previously I thought that it represent 1+3+5+7+9, but the answer is not 11.
Can anyone help me explain how does the output becomes 11? It doesn't make any sense at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last iteration of the loop is when `i = 9`. The loop terminates with `i += 2` which will give you `i = 11`.

Answer (score 4):

It's not really clear what you were expecting at all, but look at what happens:

- `i` starts off as 1. 1 is less than or equal to 10, so it enters the loop body

  - The loop body does nothing
  - At the end of the loop body, `i` is incremented by 2
- `i` now has value 3. 3 is less than or equal to 10, so it enters the loop body

  - The loop body does nothing
  - At the end of the loop body, `i` is incremented by 2
- `i` now has value 5. 5 is less than or equal to 10, so it enters the loop body

  - The loop body does nothing
  - At the end of the loop body, `i` is incremented by 2
- `i` now has value 7. 7 is less than or equal to 10, so it enters the loop body

  - The loop body does nothing
  - At the end of the loop body, `i` is incremented by 2
- `i` now has value 9. 9 is less than or equal to 10, so it enters the loop body

  - The loop body does nothing
  - At the end of the loop body, `i` is incremented by 2
- `i` now has value 11. 11 is *not* less than or equal to 10, so the loop terminates
- The value of `1` is printed - it's still 11

Comment: You beat me to the description of why, nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially your loop isn't able to terminate due to the way it is iterating through the results.

Your value for `i = 1`.

The problem is you've put `i += 2`.

The reason this will cause a problem, is because it will go through all of your values like so:

- `i = 1`: Fails for your `i <= 10` Loop will continue.
- `i = 3`: Fails for your `i <= 10` still doesn't meet criteria, loop iterates still.
- `i = 5`: Fails for your `i <= 10` not met, loop continues.
- `i = 7`: Fails for your `i <= 10` not met, loop will continue.
- `i = 9`: Fails for your `i <= 10` still does not meet your criteria.

Since that last iteration fails, it actually runs another time.  If your attempting to have the loop run a certain amount of times you'll have to use a more concise mathematical representation to iterate correctly. It doesn't balance the `i <= 10` in the desired number of times, so it results in that one extra iteration.

But that is why it is 11, because your last value fails to meet the conditions met.

Now if you want the loop to go  five times, you'd want something like this:

```
int i;
for(i = 1, i <= 5, i +=1 );
```

You could also accomplish it like this:

```
int i;
for(i = 5, i <= 20, i += 5);
```

I'm not sure if that was your original goal with different numbers, but hopefully that helps. I may of added wrong, but hopefully that points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop starts `i` at `1`, and keeps adding `2` to `i`, stopping when `i` is greater than `10`. This happens for the first time at `i == 11`, so the loop is exited and `i`’s still `11`.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the message box *inside* the loop:

```
int i;
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i += 2)
{
  MessageBox.Show("The number is " + i);
}
```

then you would get five message boxes with the values 1, 3, 5, 7 and 9.

As the message box is after the loop, you get a single message box with the value that the variable has after the loop, i.e. 11.